# how to count last 7 record of one table using mysql stored procedure ,in my query i want count isprinted as printed when isprinted=1

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_printnotprintdailyexpenses`(
in i_localBodyId varchar(10),
in i_epId int(20),

out printed INT(20),
out notprinted INT(20)


)
BEGIN
set printed=(select count(isPrinted) from tbl_dailyExpenses 
where  date((curdate() - 7)) and date(curdate())and
localBodyId =i_localBodyId and epId=i_epId and isPrinted=1 group by CURDATE()-7 );
set notprinted=(select count(isPrinted) from tbl_dailyExpenses 
where date((curdate() - 7 )) and date(curdate())and
localBodyId =i_localBodyId and epId=i_epId and isPrinted=0 group by CURDATE()-7 );
END
```

Comment: i want to count isprinted column in that isprintd  value is 0 and 1 when is printed=1 then as printed and when isprinted=0 then as notprinted this count for last 7 record date column is present in my table

Comment: What is the date field called?

Comment: no call for date

Comment: How can you tell what day something was printed on if you don't have a column which stores date values?

Comment: date is just uesd for check current date ani privous 7 record

Comment: So if there's no date field in tbl_dailyExpenses does that mean that only one entry gets written per day? What field distinguishes the entries in that table from each other? Is there an auto_incrementing id field?

Comment: this is sample query, in my main query i am added date cloumn

Comment: You need the date column in this procedure to decide which entries in tbl_dailyExpenses were in the last 7 days...

Comment: date |                    printed  |                            notprinted |                                                                           10-1-218            count on this date(2)            1                                                        15-01-2018         6                                             2                                                           and so on expected output

Comment: select date,
(select count(isprinted) from tbl_dailyExpenses  where 
 date(DATE(NOW()-7))and date(DATE(NOW())) and isprinted=1 
and localBodyId=i_localBodyId and epId=i_epId ) as printed,
 
(select count(isprinted) from tbl_dailyExpenses where 
date(DATE(NOW()-7))and date(DATE(NOW())) and isprinted=0 
and localBodyId=i_localBodyId and epId=i_epId ) as notprinted

from tbl_dailyExpenses group by date,localBodyId,epId order by date desc LIMIT 7 ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need a procedure. A simple query should suffice. Based on what I have been able to understand from this question (and the other one you asked) this should give you the results you want:

```
SELECT date,
  localBodyId,
  epId,
  SUM(CASE WHEN isPrinted=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS printed, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN isPrinted=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS notprinted
FROM tbl_dailyExpenses
WHERE localBodyId = i_localBodyId AND epId = i_epId AND
  date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
GROUP BY date, localBodyId, epId
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 7
```

In this query you will need to replace *i_localBodyId* and *i_epId* with the values you want to test.

Comment: `COUNT` won't work because it can't distinguish between values only whether a value exists or not.

Comment: If it did work it would be great if you could mark it accepted (The little tick mark under the voting arrows). That will help other users looking for similar answers.